# kubelet and dockerd process in master node use too many memory

Tags: kubernetes, centos7, kubectl

Enviroment:

> CentOS 7
>
> CPU:2 core
>
> Total Memory:  4G

Is it accpectable for the k8s master node use memory like this?
If not what should I do to trace the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgqAZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is the usual behavior of kubelet. It consumes as much memory as it needs, it depends on the number of pods, nodes, etc. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#before-you-begin) you could find the minimal requirements for K8s.